# установка SSL в Openfire

Tags: java, ssl, xmpp

Всем добрый день!
Тема вроде бы избитая, но что-то я "туплю"

Есть свежий сертификат RapidSSL и openfire 3.10.1

Использовал вот эту инструкцию: http://www.adminhelp.pro/how-to/how-to-ssl-tls/745/

При доступе через https к консоле всё ок. На сертификат нареканий нет.

Сам openfire помечает сертификат как "Pending Verification".

Не у кого такой проблемы не было?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решается командой:

> keytool -import -keystore keystore -alias xmpp.test.ru -file
>   ~/ssl/test.p7b

Файл test.p7b можно скачать из личного кабинета RapidSSL